# Which formulas can go in the axiom of (unrestricted) comprehension?

Tags: set-theory

I am taking as an example the unrestricted axiom of comprehension because it's the easiest to write, but there is something that puzzles me about how axiom schemas are formulated in literature and I would like to understand if there is something I am missing.
On PlanetMath, I found the following:

$\exists X \forall x (x \in X \leftrightarrow \phi(x))$ for any formula $\phi$ where $X$ does not occur free in $\phi$.

I would think the correct way to restrict $\phi$ would be to say that $x$ is the ONLY variable that occurs free in it. Yes, $X$ cannot occur free for obvious reasons, but any other variable that occurs free would make the whole axiom a predicate and not a sentence.

I suppose I'm either being overly pedantic or there is something fundamental that I am missing.

Comment: In the Comprehension Axiom Scheme you would quantify over whatever extra parameters are in φ. Remember Comprehension isnt a single axiom, its a way to produce an axiom for any φ

Comment: No, you aren't being pedantic. Its a wonderful question. And your intuition is exactly right. The only free variables in φ is x, or if we want to include other parameters - we quantify over those additional free variables in φ

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we take a formula with free variables as an axiom that means the same thing as taking the universal closure of the formula is an axiom. In other words, the sentence formed by universally quantifying the formula over its free variables.

So the statement on planet math is intended to allow free variables (other than $X$) and the understanding is as I said above.

I guess this is all a moot point because whether we allow other free variables or not, that axiom schema is inconsistent, but on the other hand, we could state the (consistent) separation schema as $$ \exists X\forall x( x\in X\leftrightarrow x\in A\land \varphi)$$ where $\varphi$ is a formula not including $X$ free (but perhaps including other free variables: probably (but not necessarily) $x$, but also maybe $A$, and some others).

For a version of the schema that is explicit about the universal closure, see [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification).

Comment: I think I see the point now. If $\varphi$ has an extra free variable $y$, the axiom states that there exists a different $X$ for each value of $y$. If I require that $y$ is quantified in $\varphi$, I can only generate one set $X$. Basically, the restriction I was proposing is limiting the power of the axiom.

Comment: @Thecuriousamateur Yes, that's right. Although whether there is actually any effective limitation of power in the presence of other axioms is a subtle issue. (i.e. it may be the case that with the weaker schema, and other axioms combined you can still prove the same things, perhaps with more round-about proofs. See e.g. https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/ZFC_without_parameters.pdf ... I say "may" because this kind of thing tends to be sensitive to the details of how the axioms are phrased.)